# Comparing nodes in a linked list by reference

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to compare nodes in two separate linked lists by reference and not value.
My implementation of linked list is as under

```
struct node{
    node(char data):data(data), next(nullptr){}
    char data;
    node* next;
};

class slist{
    node* head;
public:
    slist(node* head):head(head){}

    node*& getHead(){
        return head;
    }
    void insert(char item){
        node* p = new node(item);
        if(head == nullptr){
            head = p;
            return;
        }
        p->next = head;
        head = p;

    }
```

This is the overloaded operator that I use to compare two nodes by reference.

```
bool operator==(node*& p, node*& q){
    if(p->data == q->data) return true;
    return false;
}
    static node* compare(node*& p, node*& q){
        if(p == nullptr || q == nullptr) return nullptr;
        node* current1 = p;
        node* current2 = q;

        while(current1 != nullptr){
            while(current2 != nullptr){
                if(current1 == current2) return current1;
                current2 = current2->next;
            }
            current1 = current1->next;
        }
        return nullptr;

    }
};
```

The driver code is as follows:

```
 bool operator==(node*& p, node*& q){
        if(p->data == q->data) return true;
        return false;
    }

static node* intersection(node*& p, node*& q){
    if(p == nullptr || q == nullptr) return nullptr;
    node* current1 = p;
    node* current2 = q;

    while(current1 != nullptr){
        while(current2 != nullptr){
            if(current1 == current2) return current1;
            current2 = current2->next;
        }
        current1 = current1->next;
    }
    return nullptr;

}
```

The error that I keep getting is as follows:

```
error: overloaded 'operator==' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)
    bool operator==(node*& p, node*& q){
         ^
```

Comment: I'm not sure *& actually does anything for you, other than be more unreadable and open up a potential for obscure bugs. * would give you the same functionality. And really they should be const.

Answer (score 0):

Member operators always have the this pointer as an implied parameter, so you only need the other object.

```
bool operator==(node*& q){
    if(this->data == q->data) return true; //Could also just have if(data == q->data) but this is a little more explicit
    return false;
}
```

Or you can use your original as a free function, however you won't be able to use private members, unless you declare it as a friend.